# How store null in database using vue and laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have Vue project with Laravel API, and also I have a column named `expired_date: date`  it is nullable

this is the response after I dd the data from the network console:

[image]

The problem is when I store the data I just found the `expired_date` store value `0000-00-00`

My code of store:

```
$data = $request->except('image');
    
if (!$request->expired_date) {
   $data['expired_date'] = null;
}

Post::create($data);
```

Comment: if your column is nullable like: ->nullable(); The Default value should be null and it should store null if expired date has no value

Comment: @elias.xe exactly it is`->nullable()`  but I don't know why it stores zeros!

Comment: Can you verify that the migration ran correctly and the database reports that the column is nullable? `SELECT is_nullable from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<your_db>' AND table_name = 'posts' AND column_name = 'expired_date';`

Comment: Cause the default value of Date in SQL is 0000-00-00 so your need to define the default value to NULL

Comment: @TravisBritz I got the result of your query `is_nullable: YES` !

Comment: Is `expired_date` part of your `$casts` or `$dates` attribute in the Post model? (See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

Comment: @TravisBritz No, there is no nothing related to $casts or $dates@

Comment: Try adding the field to the `$casts` array as described in the docs for mutators, and see if that starts handling the field correctly. Also, what version of MySQL/Laravel are you using?

Comment: @TravisBritz I just put the filed in `$casts`as `date` and got this error: `Could not parse 'null': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (null) at position 0 (n): The timezone could not be found in the database`

Comment: Try including this in your Post model? `public function setExpiredDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['expired_date'] = empty($date) ? null : Carbon::parse($date);
}`

Comment: @TravisBritz unfortunately, still the same error as above! :(

Comment: Can you also verify the default is correct? `SELECT column_default from information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<your_db>' AND table_name = 'posts' AND column_name = 'expired_date';`

Comment: @TravisBritz `column_default NULL`

Comment: Solve it with: `$this->attributes['expired_date'] = $date === 'null' ? null : Carbon::parse($date);`

Comment: Are you saying that the frontend was sending the string "null" instead of omitting the field or sending an empty string? From your screenshot it doesn't look like the null is a string

Comment: @TravisBritz The frontend sends it to me as an empty string and if you see my code I just convert to null then for a reason that I don't know, it converts to 'null' as a string !

Comment: I was expecting the problem to be that `null` was converted to empty string `''` somewhere before serialization to the database. If it's actually the literal string `'null'` then  I'm guessing somewhere in your codebase there were accidentally quotes put around a null. I would try to find that mistake rather than doing a check for the string `'null'` in the mutator.

Comment: @TravisBritz bro couple of days, I just comment this middleware `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` in `Kernel.php` Do you except that make this problem ?

Comment: Yes, that would cause the issue.

Comment: @TravisBritz Big respect 

Comment: That doesn't explain why my check for `empty()` didn't work, but that might have been due to confusion with using it at the same time as the error with $casts. I guess the string was never `'null'`, so your check for `$date === 'null'` was actually *always* false and therefore probably always resulted in a null inserted to the database (even when there was a date). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: If that worked I'll post it as an answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that an empty string `''` is being saved instead of `null`, resulting in 0000-00-00 values saved to the field. In this case it's because the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware included with the framework was mistakenly commented out and disabled, so the solution is to re-enable that middleware.

Other common causes are forgetting to make the field nullable in the database, or having an incorrect default value.

To explicitly set a field to null without using the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware, it is possible to use a mutator similar to this inside of the model:

```php
public function setExpiredDateAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['expired_date'] = empty($date) ? null : Carbon::parse($date);
}
```